# componentWillReceiveProps not firing even props value updated

Tags: reactjs

There is simple scenario I updated a value in parent which passed to child component and expected cWRP method firing but not. here code below;

Parent component:

```
class App extends Component {
  changeProps(){//interpreter jumps here fine..
    debugger
    this.appState.index=15 //update props value
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <EasyABC parentUpdateProps={this.changeProps} appState={this.props.appState} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

child component:

```
@observer
export default class EasyABC extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){//why its not jump here after update props in parent?
        debugger
    }
    playSound(){// when this method called, cWRP above should be invoked rigth?
        this.props.parentUpdateProps()
    }

render(){
        return(
            <div>   
                <a onClick={()=> this.playSound()}>Play Sound Again</a>
```

**Edited**: i am using **mobx** as state handler, but dont bother with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the state of the component using setState and use the same for passing it to child component

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
    };
    this.changeProps = this.changeProps.bind(this);
  }

  changeProps(){
    this.setState({
      index: 15,
    });
    // this will update state (not props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <EasyABC
          parentUpdateProps={this.changeProps}
          appState={...this.state}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the `state` wrongly. You have to use `setState` e.g.

```
changeProps() {
    this.setState({
        index: 15
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to dereference the observable value in the render function or it will not fire the will receive props because the component is not actually using it to render.

You could just do something like this:

```
render() {
  if (this.props.appState.index) {
    return <div>Play Sound Again</div>;
  }

  return <div>Play Sound</div>;
}
```

It really doesn't matter how you use it, but that you access it within the call stack of the render method.